# JOIN table with itself and filter depending on subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I'm using MySQL and I would like to filter the result of table1 depending on result from subQuery. As far what I did is the 2 queries but independtly.

The first query will get me all the categories for a user:
Query 1

```
SELECT 
 `category-id` as `id`
FROM
 `categories-in-teams` as cit
    JOIN
 `user-role-teams` AS urt ON cit.`team-id` = urt.`team-id`
WHERE
 urt.`user-id` = 62
```

The result is something like :

```
100
200
300
400
```

Now on my second request I get the whole list of categories with some additional data:
Query 2

```
SELECT 
cat.`id`,
loc.`name`,
cat.`parent`,
pcat.`id` IS NULL as leaf
FROM
`product-category` AS cat
    LEFT JOIN
`product-category` as pcat ON cat.`id` = pcat.`parent`
    JOIN
`product-category-local` as loc ON cat.`id` = loc.`category-id`
    AND loc.`lang-id` = 1

GROUP BY cat.`id`
ORDER BY cat.`parent` , `name`
```

Output :

```
id      name        parent  leaf
1       Root        null    0
2       Bathroom    1       0
3       Bedroom     1       0
100     pillow      3       1
200     sofa        3       1
300     blanket     3       1
400     dunno       3       1
```

The result that I want to get from the second query will JOIN the result from the first query and exclude all the rows(categories) where `leaf` = 0 and the `id` IS NOT on `parent` column.

So from the example above, the result expected will be something like :

```
id      name        parent  leaf
1       Root        null    0
3       Bedroom     1       0
100     pillow      3       1
200     sofa        3       1
300     blanket     3       1
400     dunno       3       1
```

Comment: where is your condition `WHERE` in second query? How you get id 100,200,300,400 from second query?

Comment: @ColourDalnet I don't filter right now, The second query return everything from the database. That's the issue. I would like to filter on the rule that I said before but I still can't find out how

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
cat.`id`,
loc.`name`,
cat.`parent`,
pcat.`id` IS NULL as leaf
FROM
`product-category` AS cat
    LEFT JOIN
`product-category` as pcat ON cat.`id` = pcat.`parent`
    JOIN
`product-category-local` as loc ON cat.`id` = loc.`category-id`
    AND loc.`lang-id` = 1
WHERE cat.`id` IN (
    SELECT 
   `category-id` as `id`
    FROM
    `categories-in-teams` as cit
    JOIN
    `user-role-teams` AS urt ON cit.`team-id` = urt.`team-id`
    WHERE
    urt.`user-id` = 62
)    
OR
((pcat.`id` = 0) AND (cat.`id` IN (SELECT parent FROM `product-category`)) )
GROUP BY cat.`id`
ORDER BY cat.`parent` , `name`
```

Comment: Your query have some errors, `leaf` is an Alias for `pcat.id` and cat is also an Alias for `product-category` but even after correcting those 2 mistakes I get wrong data. for example the `root` row is not shown

Comment: @113408 : Updated, please take a screenshoot the result with that updated answer.

Comment: Your query act similar to: JOIN with the inner query and doesn't take in consideration the `OR`. If I take of the first part of the `WHERE` clause I don't get any result

Comment: You are right, I miss something in conditional, Updated. @113408